# wp-admin redirects to another page after automatic wordpress upgrade

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, upgrade, wp-admin

Whenever I try to log into my wordpress site using mysite.com/wp-admin it redirects me to mysite.com/auto-login and giving a 404 error. It is happening with mysite.com/wp-login.php page as well. After go through my email i came to know that worpdress was upgraded automatically to 4.4.6. That means the problem started after the upgrade. Before that I could log into the site using wp-admin or login.php page without any problem.

Let me tell you what I did so far to solve it.

1. Edited the .htaccess file with the default code from wordpress.org site. Problem remained.
2. After that I deleted the file and uploaded a new one.

Did both through cpanel, but all in vain.

Update: I disabled my plugins one by one and found a faulty one. wp-admin or wp-login.php is now taking me to login page. But now the problem is it keeps redirecting to this same login page every time I enter my user name and password.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache/cookies. They may have some faulty data?

Comment: Btw: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have solved it. Let me tell you how.

1. I disabled my theme by renaming the folder.
2. I had no other theme in my directory so I uploaded twentysixteen theme.
3. I tried to login and It gave me a wrong password error which was weird because I did not change anything.
4. So I went through my phpMyAdmin and found that my password was changed I don't know how. Anyway I changed that and came back to login.
   And voila! WordPress let me in!
5. Then I changed the theme to my previous real one and everything is OK now.